# Are all 'substances' made of atoms?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, elementary-particles, neutron-stars

Is there any other large collection of particles other than atoms that would fit our traditional intuitive definition of a substance?

Something that would appear similar to a solid liquid or gas.

For example, can there be a solid lump of protons or neutrons large enough to be observed with the naked eye?

Comment: Besides neutron star material there is also quark-gluon plasma. And stuff like light or neutrinos behaves as a sort of extremely dilute gas.

Comment: see   http://www.space.com/6682-neutron-star-crust-stronger-steel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally matter is composed only by atoms or molecules which are neutrally charged, a solid lump of protons is what composes the core of an atom , protons held together.
But because they all have the same charge they repel each other, the neutrons that are also in the core "glue" the protons together so that the core won't "explode" if you will.

Now when a star gets old it implodes (an explosion to the inside) and explodes, the outer layer of the star explodes (called supernova) and the core of the star implodes , and then gravity causes the matter so become more and more dense as it implodes, that's when the protons and electrons get near enough each other to recombine into neutrons, and so the core of the star implodes and becomes a neutron star.
That is a solid lump of neutrons that can be observed with the eye.

Comment: So you can't collect a load of neutrons together in a lab? They only exist in a solid mass in a neutron star?

Comment: @NickCollier, not easily.  They have no charge, so they're difficult to manipulate.  You can create individual neutrons easily, but handling them after creation is hard.  And when not in a bound state, neutrons are unstable and decay.  So if you can't gather them quickly, they'll all be gone.

Answer (score 1):

There exists something called [fermi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas)  or [bose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose_gas) gas which consits of fermions or bosons. In some sense you can say that this is like a substance.

The question is does it exists in the universe? The answer will be yes. Have a look at the [neutron stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star).